# Writing a function $ f: U \to \mathbb{R} $, where $ U $ is an open ball in $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $ centered at $ \mathbf{0} $, in terms of the dot product.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $ U $ be an open ball in $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $ centered at the origin $ \mathbf{0} $. Let $ f: U \to \mathbb{R} $ be a continuous function. Here is my question:

> If $ \displaystyle \lim_{\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{\| \mathbf{x} \|} = 0 $, then does there necessarily exist a *continuous* function $ \epsilon: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n} $ such that the following properties hold?
>
> - $ f(\mathbf{x}) = \epsilon(\mathbf{x}) \bullet \mathbf{x} $ for all
>     $ \mathbf{x} \in U $, where $ \bullet $ denotes the dot product on
>     $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $.
> - $
>     \displaystyle \lim_{\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{0}} \epsilon(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{0}
>     $.

I was able to prove the existence of $ \epsilon $ without the requirement that it be continuous on all of $ U $. The basic idea is to use the fact that the taxicab norm and the Euclidean norm on $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $ are equivalent.

Thank you very much for your kind assistance!

Comment: Are you assuming $f(0)=0$?

Comment: @Rubertos: That must be the case since $f$ is continuous and the above properties hold.

Comment: @Rubertos: That already follows from the fact that $ f $ is continuous and $ \displaystyle \lim_{\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{\| \mathbf{x} \|} = 0 $.

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable, at least at the origin?

Comment: $f$ is differentiable at the origin with derivative $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align}
\epsilon(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{|\mathbf{x}|^2}\mathbf{x}
\end{align}
which is continuous everywhere not the origin. At the origin, we see that
\begin{align}
|\epsilon(\mathbf{x})| = \frac{|f(\mathbf{x})|}{|\mathbf{x}|}\rightarrow 0
\end{align}
as $\mathbf{x} \rightarrow 0$. This shows that $\epsilon$ is continuous at the origin since $f$ is differentiable at the origin.  Moreover, we have that
\begin{align}
\epsilon(\mathbf{x})\cdot \mathbf{x} = f(\mathbf{x}).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! This was easier than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\phi(x) = \begin{cases} {f(x) \over \|x\|}, & x \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$. By assumption $\phi$ is continuous
on $U$ and $\phi(0) = 0$.

Let $\epsilon(x) = \begin{cases} \phi(x) {x \over \|x\|}, & x \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.